# How to avoid rats biting/chewing a car's wiring and interior?

Tags: electrical

We have a problem where if a vehicle is parked up for more than a week rats are biting and chewing at the wiring and dashboard.

What is the reason for this and is there any way we can prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 2):

There's various theories on *why* rats and other rodents chew on car wiring - from them using it sharpen and clean their teeth to manufacturers using soy-based coating on wires (for biodegradability) and this being tasty for them.

To be honest though the *why* is probably secondary to stopping it happening. There's lots of "home remedies" people suggest for this with various levels of success but one I've seen consistently remarked upon as being effective is to wrap the affected wires and ducts in [anti-rodent tape](https://www.motoelectrical.co.uk/types/anti-rodent-insulation-tape/anti-rodent-rat-mouse-mice-proof-electrical-insulation-tape-honda-4019-2317-20m-1200450/), this is what Honda recommend to their customers (I believe they even supplied it through their dealers at one point). The tape is infused with Capsaicin which tastes/smells horrible to rats, mice and other rodents.

Comment: You can also make a capsaicin spray by cooking a lot of chilis in water, and spray down the rat targeted areas. Keep in mind the process of making the spray will stink up your house some and keep any of the liquid away from your skin and eyes.

Comment: you can... and that is certainly quicker and easier to do (wrapping things in tape is tedious and time consuming) but will have to be re-applied frequently if this is a long term situation. If the exposure to the rats is a one-off or pretty infrequent then it's probably better to go with the spray otherwise I'd go with the tape.

Comment: So, you suggest the OP should cover the dashboard in that tape as well? May be easier to get a good cat...

Comment: good point re: dashboard.. not sure what to suggest on that one, although if it the rats are roaming around/eating the car interior I'd suggest calling a pest-control expert (or cat!) rather than a mechanic.